# Linux Kernel v2.6.34 Compilation error on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, software-installation, kernel, compiling, gcc

I am freshman in the Kernel development. I am trying to install [Linux Kernel v2.6.34](http://ftp.ntu.edu.tw/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/) on Ubuntu 16.04, because most of the books explains this version that's why I think it is a good start. My ultimate goal is to understand and modify memory management (especially in the latest Kernel). During compilation I have encountered with the following errors.

```
/home/irfan/kernel/linux-2.6.34/arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:204:33: note: in expansion of macro ‘percpu_to_op’
 #define percpu_write(var, val)  percpu_to_op("mov", var, val)
                                 ^
/home/irfan/kernel/linux-2.6.34/arch/x86/include/asm/irq_regs.h:26:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘percpu_write’
  percpu_write(irq_regs, new_regs);
  ^
arch/x86/kernel/quirks.c: In function ‘ich_force_enable_hpet’:
arch/x86/kernel/quirks.c:98:2: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
  u32 uninitialized_var(rcba);
  ^
arch/x86/kernel/quirks.c:104:36: error: ‘rcba’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  pci_read_config_dword(dev, 0xF0, &rcba);
                                    ^
arch/x86/kernel/quirks.c:104:36: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
arch/x86/kernel/quirks.c: In function ‘old_ich_force_hpet_resume’:
arch/x86/kernel/quirks.c:188:2: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
  u32 uninitialized_var(gen_cntl);
  ^
arch/x86/kernel/quirks.c:193:43: error: ‘gen_cntl’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  pci_read_config_dword(cached_dev, 0xD0, &gen_cntl);
                                           ^
arch/x86/kernel/quirks.c: In function ‘old_ich_force_enable_hpet’:
arch/x86/kernel/quirks.c:210:2: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
  u32 uninitialized_var(gen_cntl);
  ^
arch/x86/kernel/quirks.c:215:36: error: ‘gen_cntl’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  pci_read_config_dword(dev, 0xD0, &gen_cntl);
                                    ^
arch/x86/kernel/quirks.c: In function ‘vt8237_force_enable_hpet’:
arch/x86/kernel/quirks.c:301:2: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
  u32 uninitialized_var(val);
  ^
arch/x86/kernel/quirks.c:311:36: error: ‘val’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  pci_read_config_dword(dev, 0x68, &val);
                                    ^
arch/x86/kernel/quirks.c: In function ‘nvidia_force_enable_hpet’:
arch/x86/kernel/quirks.c:426:2: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
  u32 uninitialized_var(val);
  ^
arch/x86/kernel/quirks.c:437:36: error: ‘val’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  pci_read_config_dword(dev, 0x44, &val);
                                    ^
scripts/Makefile.build:230: recipe for target 'arch/x86/kernel/quirks.o' failed
make[2]: *** [arch/x86/kernel/quirks.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:366: recipe for target 'arch/x86/kernel' failed
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/kernel] Error 2
Makefile:884: recipe for target 'arch/x86' failed
make: *** [arch/x86] Error 2
```

I tried, but I didn't success, nor I found any material/help about this error.

Comment: 2.6.34 is from 2010 and out of support for over five years now. Better try a modern version instead.

Comment: If you look at the release announcement for the 2.6 branch, it'll list the assumptions required to build it (which will likely be a rather old versions of `gcc` etc; much older than what you probably trying to make with)

Answer (score 0):

Books you're reading are just outdated. Ubuntu 16.04 comes with kernel 4.4. Anything below this verion is simply too old to build on modern distros. Go to https://www.kernel.org/ for longterm versions of linux kernels, and look for books that keeps up with modern days. Not to mention that 16.04 is also 3 years old. You should consider at least current LTS version instead.

Comment: @Byte Commander, you are absolutely right.  I tried many thing, i.e., https://kernelnewbies.org/ but I didn't find any good material related to the latest Kernels that's why I choose to start from there. Would be grateful, If you could suggest me any good place to start?

Comment: Actually it's better to play with distro's documentation: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel - it's also a bit old, but not that much. Keep in mind that kernel compilation process has not changed much over years. But there are diffrent methods of how you ship it to the bootloader, in a way that reflects your distro's setup. You should just stick with up-to-date versions of kernels, that are as close as possible to distro's default kernel.